# How to Scroll to bottom of div (chat) - synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I'm trying to create a chat application. Every time the user sends a new message, the new message gets appended to a ul list of messages. I have made the UL list scrollable and it is scrolling overtime I send a message; however it is not scrolling all the way to the bottom. FYI: I'm using Vue.js

This is current code:

```
this.messages.push(this.currentMessage) //adding new message to the list
var div = document.getElementById('chat-list-ul');
div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
```

It somehow just scrolls to one line before the bottom. Doing some testing I discovered that it maybe caused by the scroll function being called too fast, because if I insert a timeout of 1s, it will scroll correctly.

My question is: is there a way to create a promise for the array.push() function that will allow me to call the scroll method only after the array has gotten update with the new value?

Thank you,

Comment: Create a dummy element at the bottom and scroll to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Vue.nextTick(callback)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue) to wait for the DOM to be updated after pushing the new message before you trigger the scroll. Something like this ..

```
this.messages.push(this.currentMessage) //adding new message to the list
Vue.nextTick(function () {
    var div = document.getElementById('chat-list-ul');
    div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
})
```